# GET request with Node JS stops consoling after a while when using fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch-api

I am trying to make a calendar app with node, mongodb, html, css and javascript. I want the user to insert dates as events and that works for me. I want to fetch these dates from the client side and console them on the server side. The problem is that when I'm trying to console them on the server they are consoled and after a while stops and app crashes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZhNE.png) This is the app.

The client side code is this. The makedates function creates the calendar dynamically. The fetchevents func makes the get request to the server. The changedates func changes the months on the calendar and I'm using the fetchevents func inside the changedates func

```js
const makedates = (currentmonth, currentyear) => {
  var firstDay = new Date(currentyear, currentmonth, 1);
  var lastDay = new Date(currentyear, currentmonth + 1, 0);
  var lastdayprev = new Date(currentyear, currentmonth, 0);
  var firstdaynext = new Date(currentyear, currentmonth + 1, 1);

  const p =
    firstDay.getDay() === 0
      ? days[days.length - 1]
      : days[firstDay.getDay() - 1];
  var nextdaysofmonth = firstdaynext.getDate();
  var sum = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < days.length - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < days.length; j++) {
      if (i === 0) {
        if (days.indexOf(p) === j) {
          if (
            firstDay.getDate() === date.getDate() &&
            currentmonth == date.getMonth() &&
            currentyear == date.getFullYear()
          ) {
            dates.innerHTML += `<li class="today">${firstDay.getDate()}</li>`;
          } else {
            dates.innerHTML += `<li>${firstDay.getDate()}</li>`;
          }

          sum = firstDay.getDate();
        } else if (days.indexOf(p) < j) {
          if (
            sum === date.getDate() &&
            currentmonth == date.getMonth() &&
            currentyear == date.getFullYear()
          ) {
            dates.innerHTML += `<li class="today">${sum}</li>`;
          } else {
            dates.innerHTML += `<li >${sum}</li>`;
          }
        } else {
          const prev = lastdayprev.getDate() - days.indexOf(p) + 1 + j;

          dates.innerHTML += `<li class="previous">${prev}</li>`;
        }
      } else {
        if (sum > lastDay.getDate()) {
          const prev = lastdayprev.getDate() - days.indexOf(p) + 1 + j;

          dates.innerHTML += `<li class="next">${nextdaysofmonth}</li>`;
          nextdaysofmonth += 1;
        } else {
          if (
            sum === date.getDate() &&
            currentmonth == date.getMonth() &&
            currentyear == date.getFullYear()
          ) {
            dates.innerHTML += `<li class="today">${sum}</li>`;
          } else {
            dates.innerHTML += `<li>${sum}</li>`;
          }
        }
      }

      sum += 1;
    }
    // dates.innerHTML+=`<br>`;
  }
  activedays();
};
const fetchevents = (month, year) => {
  const endpoint = `/Dashboard/Add_Note/`;
  fetch(endpoint + `${month}` + `/${year}`, {
    method: "GET",
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
const changedates = () => {
  arrow_next.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (currentmonth === 11) {
      currentyear += 1;
      currentmonth = 0;
    } else {
      currentmonth += 1;
    }

    current_month.innerText = months[currentmonth];
    current_year.innerText = currentyear;
    dates.innerHTML = ``;
    todoevents.innerHTML = "";
    makedates(currentmonth, currentyear);
    fetchevents(months[currentmonth], currentyear);
  });
  arrow_prev.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (currentmonth === 0) {
      currentyear -= 1;
      currentmonth = 11;
    } else {
      currentmonth -= 1;
    }
    current_month.innerText = months[currentmonth];
    current_year.innerText = currentyear;
    dates.innerHTML = ``;
    todoevents.innerHTML = "";
    makedates(currentmonth, currentyear);
    fetchevents(months[currentmonth], currentyear);
  });
};
```

the server side code.

```js
app.get("/Dashboard/Add_Note/:month/:year", (req, res) => {
  const month = req.params.month;
  const year = req.params.year;
  console.log(month);
  console.log(year);
});
```

As you see I have month and year as params and these are that Im trying to console. Any idea what am I doing wrong? I am new to node

Comment: You should send a response from your route handler... `res.json({ mesage: "some response" })`

Comment: FYI you seem to be missing the advantages of string template literals. Try `fetch(\`/Dashboard/Add_Note/${month}/${year}\`, ...` (this isn't an answer, just an improvement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that when I'm trying to console them on the server they are consoled and after a while stops and app crashes.

Your server never sends a response from this request handler:

```
app.get("/Dashboard/Add_Note/:month/:year", (req, res) => {
  const month = req.params.month;
  const year = req.params.year;
  console.log(month);
  console.log(year);
});
```

Because of that, the client just sits waiting and waiting and waiting for a response.  After a certain number of requests, the browser will no longer send more requests until some of the prior ones return a response because the browser is already waiting for requests from the same host.

To fix, ALWAYS send a response from every incoming request on your server.

```
app.get("/Dashboard/Add_Note/:month/:year", (req, res) => {
  const month = req.params.month;
  const year = req.params.year;
  console.log(month);
  console.log(year);
  res.send("got your data");
});
```

This will free up the browser so it doesn't start queuing up requests to that same host.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This worked and also helped a lot to understand more about the server.